# Как создать цикличность что бы работали обе кнопки и не 1 раз

Tags: java, android

подскажите как сделать так что бы работало все.

при нажатии на кнопку первый раз происходит весь алгоритм( идет замена лейаутов, так же замена кнопок) но вот второй процесс не делает ничего( то есть прописан код наоборот что бы можно было переключаться с 1 режима на другой). Уже все пересмотрел, какой оператор помог бы в этом вопросе не нашел

(переменная булиан просто так лежит, пытался сделать через if else но тут всего 1 цикл идет и он не повторяется по нажатию)

```
   package com.example.magictrans;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class fullcalc extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button barter1;
        Button barter2;
        boolean barter =false;
        LinearLayout doppoint;
        LinearLayout point;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fullcalc);

            barter1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.barter1);
            barter2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.barter2);
            doppoint = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.doppoint);
            point = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.point);
            barter1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        doppoint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        point.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        barter1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        barter2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            barter2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        doppoint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        point.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        barter1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        barter2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
        }
}
```

Update
Вопрос решил сам через логику if else

```
package com.example.magictrans;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class fullcalc extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button barter1;
        boolean barter =false;
        LinearLayout doppoint;
        LinearLayout point;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fullcalc);

            barter1 = findViewById(R.id.barter1);
            doppoint = findViewById(R.id.doppoint);
            point = findViewById(R.id.point);
            barter1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (!barter) {
                    barter = true;
                    barter1.setText("Объем");
                            doppoint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            point.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else {
                    barter=false;
                    barter1.setText("Габариты");
                    doppoint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    point.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

теперь нормально переключается между 1 и 2 лойаутом много раз через параметр визибилити.

Comment: Ух, не знал, что javascript резко сменил синтаксис

Comment: — Java. — Script? — Ну типа)))

Comment: я 1 раз тут((( используя if else получается сделать кнопку, но процесс происходит 1 раз всего, а мне нужно что бы он повторялся после каждого нажатия. Типо 1 раз нажал тогда 1 лаяут появляется второй скрывается, втроой раз нажал происходит наоборот и так до бесконечности по нажатию на кнопку. Уже и вложил и отдельные кнопки сделал и через визибили кнопок пытаюсь не получается чет

Comment: @Bulbash, код относительно верный, попробуйте `View.INVISIBLE` заменить на `View.GONE` возможно из-за этого у вас barter2 просто не нажимается, еще можно упростить и все перенести в 1 функцию, например `doppoint.setVisibility(doppoint.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: спасибо решил вопрос через 1 кнопку)))) одновременно с вами, видимо забыл давать в Else boolean false поэтому не переключался